# Download PDF and Word file in UWP

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word, uwp

Currently i'm working on UWP apps, In that i need to download the pdf and word url to the system downloads folder, for that need i'm trying backgrounddownloader class as shown in below code.

```
 Uri source = new Uri(selectedfile.DocumentPath);

            StorageFile destinationFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(
               selectedfile.DocumentName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

            BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
            DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(source, destinationFile);
```

An also i'm trying another way to download the urls here is the code

```
  var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(selectedfile.DocumentPath);

            var sampleFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(selectedfile.DocumentName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
                var cli = new HttpClient();
                var str = await cli.GetStreamAsync(request.RequestUri);
                var dst = await sampleFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
                await str.AsInputStream().AsStreamForRead().CopyToAsync(dst);
```

For using above two methods url can be downloaded as pdf and word but i'm trying to open the pdf file and word file but it couldn't open, it showing error like as shown in below figure [trying to open the open downloaded file it shown like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GWN5.png). Can any one help to solve this issue. I want to download the file and also downloaded file should be open.

Comment: You haven't posted the complete code. Using the first method, do you wait for the download to complete? In the second one, do you close the destination stream?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in first method i'm not wait to download, it downloads automatically and showing the file in pictures folder, I don't know above methods are correct or not, I'm just trying that methods.

Comment: It should be the host not giving you the expected file, maybe an html file instead. Open the downloaded file with notepad and you will find out, if this is the case.

Comment: I'm trying to open the download file with notepad, it shown like as shown in below code. %PDF-1.6
%âãÏÓ
191 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/First 6/Length 131/N 1/Type/ObjStm>>stream
hÞ241Q0P°±Ñw.JM,ÉÌÏsI,IÕp±22046032022²t
ÌÕ
Ô5!ªò‹4\Üt#œ3óÒSŒõ4õ}óS:ÍL
Í
Mt
L :ŠòSJ“SÑµšèlRˆÑÏÌKÉ//V¨03‰ÑÔ´³0 R)E
endstream
endobj
192 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/First 6/Length 122/N 1/Type/ObjStm>>stream
hÞ,Ž±

Comment: Can any one tell above methods are the right way to download the files or any another way to download the PDF and Word files in UWP

Comment: Did you save the file with .pdf suffix?

Comment: Yes @SunteenWu-MSFT i'm saving the file with .pdf suffix that means report.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The `BackgroundDownloader.CreateDownload` method initializes a [`DownloadOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.downloadoperation) object that contains the specified Uri and the file that the response is written to.

When the `DownloadOperation` is created, it does not starts the download operation.
We should be able to use `DownloadOperation.StartAsync` to start the download operation.

For example:

```
Uri source = new Uri(selectedfile.DocumentPath);
StorageFile destinationFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("ab.pdf", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(source, destinationFile);
await download.StartAsync();
```

If you want to know more detail about down load file, please refer the [Background transfer sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer).